# How to group data on server side in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I would like to ask if there is some piece of code which provides example of grouping data server side in slick grid? I found a way to order data and filter it but grouping data with multi column sorting seems to be very hard to implement. Can you provide some examples how to handle this?

Cheers

Comment: may you add your effort with a snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) repo. In the 'Data Centric' section of the [examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) page there are two multi column sort examples.

As for server side, Slickgrid is a javascript component and so knows nothing about server side activity. To sort server side, you'd need to sort the data on the server (PHP, C#, Node - your choice), return the data as a JSON object and plug it back into the grid. Much easier just to use the multi column sort.